# ¿Cómo puedo validar si un carácter de respuesta de curl es 1 o 0?

Tags: curl, grep

Quiero saber si es 1 o 0 el valor de una cadena que obtengo por curl en una web:

tecleo:

```
curl "http://admin:password@192.168.15.107/io.cgi?"
```

Responde:

```
relays 0000
outputs 00000000
inputs 00000000
```

Quiero saber si el relay en la posición 4 es un uno o cero.

- relays 0000 -> 0
- relays 0001 -> 1

¿Se puede hacer con un grep o algo así?

He probado esto:

```
echo ${curl "http://admin:password@192.168.15.107/io.cgi?":10:1}
```

Pero me da error.

Comment: Cuando dices "quiero saber", ¿a qué te refieres exactamente? ¿Quieres guardar ese valor o hacer una cosa u otra según lo que valga, directamente?

Answer (score 0):

Yo optaría por Awk, para hacerlo más sucinto:

```
curl ... | awk '/^relays/ {print substr($2, 4, 1)}'
```

Lo que hace esto es filtrar la línea que empieza por "relays" y, en ella, imprimir el 4.º carácter del segundo campo.

---

Es buena idea lo que planteas de:

```
echo ${curl "http://admin:password@192.168.15.107/io.cgi?":10:1}
```

Sin embargo, para que funcione debes coger primer la línea en sí y guardarla en una variable:

```
valor=$(curl ... | grep "^relays")
echo ${valor:10:1}
```

---

Nótese que muy probablemente `curl` te muestre mucho contenido "verboso", como el de la evolución de la descarga y demás. Para ello, siempre es aconsejable usar `curl -s ...` para que sea silencioso.